# How i can fade in and fade out words after 5 seconds using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fade

i want to display some words on my webpage after some frequency of time. e.g i have these words.

```
     marriage,birthday,annual dinner,school
```

And i have this line display at the top of page "We arrange these type of events like 'marriage' "

after some seconds next word birthday will replace marriage and then next on and this scanario continues.

I didn't find any best jquery plugin.

If anyone knows please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo with fade animation](http://jsbin.com/ecekub/1/edit)*

HTML:

```
<h2> "We arrange these type of events like <span>marriage</span> "</h2>
```

jQuery:

```
var c=0, words=['marriage','birthday','annual dinner','school'];


function loop(){
  $('h2 span').delay(1000).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
     $(this).text( words[++c%words.length] ).fadeTo(300,1,loop);
  });
}    
loop(); // start it!
```

---

if you like more some real animations you could go for:

### *[jsBin demo with slide animation](http://jsbin.com/ecekub/5/edit)*

```
function loop(){
  $('h2 span').delay(1000).animate({top:-50},300,function(){
    $(this).css({top:100}).text( words[++c%words.length]).animate({top:0},300,loop);
  });
}
loop(); // start it!
```

having `h2{overflow:hidden}` and `h2 span{position:relative;}`

Just make sure to use a `H2` more specific selector like `$('#fade_title span')`

Comment: @KashifAli THanks! I forgot to mention, just increase the delay to 4400 :) happy coding

Comment: If i increase no of words in array then need to any change in code?

Comment: @KashifAli nothing. Just plug and play :D THe `words.length` is taking care for that!

Comment: +1 Interesting! what does the `%` in `[++c%words.length]` means actually?

Comment: actually let's start from `.fadeTo(300,1,loop);` that 'loop' callback will actually really LOOP your function. now, at each loop iteration ++c being '0' will increment by 1. Than at some point we need to reset that c back to '0', right if we want to see our first 'word' again: ++c%words.length where '%' is *Modulus* and will return a reminder of c that 4%4 = 0.

Comment: if have this array words=words=['marriage','birthday','annual dinner','school','ali','soop','google','Gogo']; then after ali words are not display and after ali the word marriage show again.Check it please

Comment: @KashifAli I see you have `words=words=` and that's wrong. Any way if that is a typo I don't know what r y doing wrong cause it simply works. just add as many words you want. http://jsbin.com/ecekub/4/edit